# Endeca Monitor 1.0.2 -- Not capture values for measures except HostReachable

Tags: plugins, endeca, dynatrace

I have configured the DynaTrace Endeca plugin and set all it's configurable values including protocol, port, and host. Then I created a Chart and added series for HostReachable measure which show value 1 all the time. Then I added NumOfRequest series but it shows message `No measurements available for selected timeframe`. How do I capture chart values for this measure. Apart for HostReachable I'm not able to capture any values for other measures.

In "add series" dialog I can see one row in Splitting Value section (`Endecamonitor@abc.xyz.org`) only for HostReachable measure. This could be one of the reason but not sure.

Following is latest logs:

```
2016-08-17 09:55:45 INFO [EndecaMonitor@Prod Endeca Monitor_0] info 
2016-08-17 09:55:45 INFO [EndecaMonitor@Prod Endeca Monitor_0] Executing method: , URI: http://abc.xyz.org:12345/admin?op=stats 
2016-08-17 09:55:45 INFO [EndecaMonitor@Prod Endeca Monitor_0] Parrsing XML from: http://abc.xyz.org:12345/admin?op=stats 
2016-08-17 10:00:45 INFO [EndecaMonitor@Prod Endeca Monitor_0] info 
2016-08-17 10:00:45 INFO [EndecaMonitor@Prod Endeca Monitor_0] Executing method: , URI: http://abc.xyz.org:12345/admin?op=stats 
2016-08-17 10:00:45 INFO [EndecaMonitor@Prod Endeca Monitor_0] Parrsing XML from: http://abc.xyz.org:12345/admin?op=stats
```